Thunderbird compose window dark mode
Using the Dark Reader add-on for Thunderbird (128.4.1esr 64-bit) one sees all the email content in dark mode. Not different from how Dark Reader shows web content in dark mode.
Is there some way to get the compose window content to be in dark mode? For comparison, if dark mode is enabled in Outlook the compose window content is also in dark mode.

Which Thunderbird version are you using that you need an addon? Dark theme has been available by default for a while

128.4.1esr (64-bit). The theme only affects the chrome. I want the content of the emails and the email that I am composing to be in dark mode.

For dark mode in the compose window, you can try the 'Dracula for Thunderbird' theme.
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/dracula-theme-for-thunderbird/
It's not the newest one, but has great reviews and 1500+ users. Should be compatible with your version (suitable for TB 60+) and should have support of dark mode in compose windows.
After installing:

Go to Add-ons and Themes
Enable the Dracula theme
Restart Thunderbird

Note: You might want to disable Dark Reader while using this theme to avoid conflicts to test it.
